# Handling unclosed divs (and other problematic HTML code) in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tinymce

I have an html page with a TinyMCE editor in it.
In the editor I would like to edit HTML code that I get from external source.
Some of the HTML I want to edit are problematic, for example I had one code with an unclosed div. What happens in that case, is that the rest of the HTML (after the TinyMCE editing part) gets messed up - because the rest of the HTML is not parsed properly, and that's understood.

The question is how to solve this issue.

Approach 1 - Is to try and solve it on the server side. That's problematic, because I don't want to actually touch/modify that HTML source, the editing process that I need the Tinymce for is just for language changes by the editor. If I'd implement some HTML fixing mechanism on the server side, I might end up with automatic changes to the HTML I didn't plan to.

Approach 2 - If I had some  tag in HTML - that would be great - and tag in which the html code in it does not effect the outside code. Do I have that kind of tag?

Approach 3 - Is to think of putting the HTML code inside an inline IFRAME. The problem here is that my control buttons for SUBMIT are outside of the IFRAME - and the TinyMCE is in the IFRAME, so how would I do the Javascript communication then?

Approach 4- Is to wrap the HTML code given to the tinyMCE with an  tag, and then after editing, to strip it out. Would that sound like a decent solution? I couldn't actually succeed in wrapping the html in an iframe inside on the tinymce input.

What do you guys say?